# MacOS Core Audio CAF recording produces all zeros

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-audio, audio-recording

I'm following the *Learning Core Audio* book tutorial, in chapter 4 there is an exercise which consists of creating a queue of buffers, listen to the default input microphone and save the buffer in a `caf` file.
I tried to execute the code, which also the author provides a version, several times. But all the times all I get is a 30kb caf file with the leading and trailing magic cookies, and all zeroes in the middle.

**xxd output.caf excerpt:**

```
00006fb0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006fc0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006fd0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006fe0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

I tried to reset the microphone privacy preferences a lot of times, allowed the use of microphone in settings for both XCode and terminal, executed the CLI application both in the debug and release mode and in different folders, but nothing changed. All I get is a 30kb *caf* files, no matter the duration.

I don't think it's much useful reporting all the code, since it seems to work for other people. But here is the callback implementation:

```
// Audio Queue callback function, called when an input buffer has been filled.
static void MyAQInputCallback(void *inUserData, AudioQueueRef inQueue,
                              AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime,
                              UInt32 inNumPackets,
                              const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDesc)
{
    MyRecorder *recorder = (MyRecorder *)inUserData;

    // if inNumPackets is greater then zero, our buffer contains audio data
    // in the format we specified (AAC)
    if (inNumPackets > 0)
    {
        // write packets to file
        CheckError(AudioFileWritePackets(recorder->recordFile, FALSE, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                         inPacketDesc, recorder->recordPacket, &inNumPackets,
                                         inBuffer->mAudioData), "AudioFileWritePackets failed");
        // increment packet index
        recorder->recordPacket += inNumPackets;
    }

    // if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffer so that it gets filled again
    if (recorder->running)
        CheckError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inQueue, inBuffer,
                                           0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
}
```

I tried printing some variables and it feels everything fine. Tell me if you want the output of some variable or some other piece of code.

I'm aware that it's very hard for you to be helpful with so little information, but I really need this feature working and I hope that you can at least make some supposition or guide me through debugging.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:**

> All I get is a 30kb caf files, no matter the duration.

This could solved by

```
CheckError(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, // ASBD
                              MyAQInputCallback, // Callback
                              &recorder, // user data
                              NULL, // run loop
                              NULL, // run loop mode
                              0, // flags (always 0)
                              &queue),
           "AudioQueueNewInput failed");
```

run loop &  run loop mode， both NULL.

---

**Secondly:**

In iOS , both devices and simulators,

It is OK to use `AudioQueueNewInput`  to do recording.

In OS X terminal app,

```
produces all zeros
```

---

printing some variables and not OK

print like this

```
 CheckError(AudioFileWritePackets(recorder->recordFile, FALSE, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                     inPacketDesc, recorder->recordPacket, &inNumPackets,
                                     inBuffer->mAudioData), "AudioFileWritePackets failed");

 printf("\ninBuffer->mAudioData: %d\n", inBuffer->mAudioData);
```

In my Mbp, it repeats on

> 25556992

> 25492480

So `AudioQueueNewInput`  works badly

---

I also tried the swift version of

> the Learning Core Audio book tutorial

met the same issue.

Here is Swift Version callback code:

```
func inputCallback(userData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                   queue: AudioQueueRef,
                   bufferToEmpty: AudioQueueBufferRef,
                   startTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                   numPackets: UInt32,
                   packetDesc: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) {




    // cast the inUserData Void pointer to a Recorder struct pointer
    let recorder = userData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: Recorder.self)

    // if inNumPackets is greater then zero, our buffer contains audio data
    // in the format we specified (AAC)
    if numPackets > 0 {
    
         // write packets to file
         var ioNumPackets = numPackets
         let temp = bufferToEmpty.pointee.mAudioData
    
         let val = temp.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self).pointee
    
         print("\n\n bufferToEmpty.pointee.mAudioData", val)
         print("recorder.recordFile!", recorder.pointee.recordFile!)
         print("bufferToEmpty.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize", bufferToEmpty.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize)
    
         print("Int64(numPackets)", Int64(numPackets))
         Utility.check(error: AudioFileWritePackets(recorder.pointee.recordFile!,               // AudioFileID
                                               false,                                       // use cache?
                                               bufferToEmpty.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize,    // number of bytes to be written
                                               packetDesc,                                  // pointer to an array of PacketDescriptors
                                               recorder.pointee.recordPacket,              // index of first packet to be written
                                               &ioNumPackets,                               // number of packets to be written
                                               bufferToEmpty.pointee.mAudioData),           // buffer of audio to be written
                  operation: "AudioFileWritePackets failed")
    
         // increment packet index
          recorder.pointee.recordPacket = recorder.pointee.recordPacket + Int64(numPackets)
    }

// if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffer so that it gets filled again
    if recorder.pointee.running {
           Utility.check(error: AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue,                                     // queue
                                                 bufferToEmpty,                             // buffer to enqueue
                                                 0,                                         // always 0 for recording
                                                 nil),                                      // always nil for recording
                  operation: "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed")
     }
}
```